# JSF 2.0 and custom path in @WebServlet

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2

I have a JSF webapp with some standard JSF pages and backing beans.
I am trying to use the `urlPatterns` parameter of the `@WebServlet` annotation to get my app pages served from a non-root path. Ex:

```
http://localhost/<appName>/<myPath>/index.xhtml
```

where myPath = /web as shown in the code below.

This doesn't seem to work. The application only response to requests made to:

```
http://localhost/<appName>/index.xhtml
```

The application is deployed in Tomcat 7.0.
And the following JSF dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas?

```
import javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/web",
            initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE",
                           value = "Development") })
public class AppServlet implements Servlet {

    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        servlet.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return servlet.getServletConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return servlet.getServletInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        servlet.init(servletConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        servlet.service(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something inappriate about this question? Why the downvotes?

Comment: Not sure. Try to not use `[java]` tag for future JavaEE/JSF/Servlet related questions as there are too many naive users out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL pattern of `/web` matches only and only the `http://localhost/<appName>/web` folder and not the subfolders and files like `http://localhost/<appName>/web/index.xhtml` as you seemed to expect. For that, you should use an URL pattern of `/web/*`.

```
@WebServlet("/web/*")
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this won't work together with JSF as its own `FacesServlet` would not be invoked this way. Perhaps you actually need a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)? Also, that web init parameter creates a `<servlet><init-param>` and not a `<context-param>` as usually required for JSF. Just in case you didn't knew that.

Comment: Ah - I see. So many things learnt from one question :-) Thanks very much for this answer. Using the URL `\web\*` in web.xml works! One small issue, however, is that the webapp still responds to request to `http://localhost/<webapp/index.xhtml` where index.xhtml is a JSF page - I did not expect this. I thought that the /web/* URL filter is saying the FacesServlet should ONLY handle requests of the form `http://localhost/<webapp>/web/*` is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: If it still responds on non-/web-requests, then you apparently already have a `FacesServlet` configured in `web.xml` which is mapped on `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`. But if you actually want to run `FacesServlet` on `/web/*` only, then you should change the URL pattern in `web.xml` to `<url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>`. There's absolutely no need to create such a servlet delegating to the `FacesServlet`.

Comment: Great! Will investigate. Thanks ever so much you saved me hours of pulling my hair out! :-)